# Can I remove duplicate run configurations from Eclipse view?

Tags: java, eclipse, run-configuration

I have Maven parent project with children.

When I go to *Run -> Run Configurations...* in *Java Application* I see few launchers twice - the only difference is path in *Common* tab, section *Save as... Shared file*.

I can't even rename one of them without renaming the second.

Is there a way to at least hide one of two same-named entries? Because now it's a little confusing when you look at it without wider spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch configurations appear as duplicates in Eclipse if the following conditions apply:

- the launch configurations are contained in a project
- the project is part of a Maven Module Project
- both projects are open in your workspace

Your hinted that "the only difference is path in Common tab". Comparing the paths will look like:

- "\moduleProject\containedProject"-path
- "\containedProject"-path

Solution: Close the Maven Module Project in your workspace.

Comment: I need to have both opened - parent for updating whole repository at once and childrens to work on them.

Comment: Actually I realized that I can update the whole repository from any child, so I am accepting this one.