# Hide duplicated run configurations without closing parent project or child project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This question is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026737/can-i-remove-duplicate-run-configurations-from-eclipse-view/55723378?noredirect=1#comment98165470_55723378) but I have an additionnal question because I cannot use the solution which was provided in this post.

If I understand well the solution it tells to close the maven module project which repeat the run configuration.

But what if I cannot close the Maven Module Project ?

At the moment I have the Project Explorer view in hierarchical presentation mode. So I cannot close the parent module if I want to access to child modules.

[My project Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZP7T.png)

And I'm annoyed with the duplication of the run configurations. For each run config eclipse sees one in the parent project and the other one in the child module containing the run config.

In Common tab of a run config I see something like
Shared File: \childmodule
And the duplicated one is:
Shared File: \parentmodule\path\to\childmodule
I understand that eclipse sees it twice because parent and child modules are both opened.

But how can I do to keep my Project Explorer hierarchical view and close the parent module ?

I tried to delete the .project file of parent but eclipse create it again when I re-import my whole project (I import projects from git local repo).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for my problem.

I prefer to answer my question in case it can help someone...

So basically I had to add filters in my .project files of top projects in my hierarchy.

As following: [Screenshot workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpDAx.png)

The filter I applied is used to ignore specific folders which are actually subprojects.